# Webflux How to process data twice

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I have code like this:

```java
serviceA.doSomething()
    .map(dataA -> serviceB.doSth(dataA))
    .map(dataB -> serviceC.doSth(dataA, dataB)) // How to access dataA again ?
```

The problem is, I want to use `dataA` twice, but it cannot be accessed on the second map (`serviceC`)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is

```java
serviceA.doSomething()
    .map(dataA -> serviceB.doSth(dataA).map(dataB -> serviceC.doSth(dataA, dataB)))
```

Note that `map()` you used is for synchronous transformations i.e. functions that don't do any asynchronous calls. On the contrary, if another service you call does perform async calls `flatMap()` should be used instead.